# Setting one of my fixed column type to string and show it through gridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a data in sqlite database that I want to show through datagridview. The data type of this data consist of datetime, Int, varchar.
[image]

[image]

So I have been looking around for answer on how to set one of my column in my datatable to be shown in my gridview as Date only. I have search some of the possible solution such as cloning the datatable and formatting the gridview column defaultcellstyle format as shown below.

```
gridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

However I can't seems to get past the error. The error with my code is if I put the following code first, it will show

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.'

```
da.Fill(dt);
```

but if I set the defaultcellstyleformat first, there won't be any data in the datatable column and hence it will show another error.

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

I do understand the error, however I can't seems to find a solution. Anyone has any idea on how to fix this? If there is already a question that has the solution for this please do show it to me and I will remove this question. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
This is the code that I use .

SQLiteConnection conn2 = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = C:\sqlite\LunchOrder.db");

```
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select d.dl_Date AS Date, e.dept_Name AS Department, e.emp_ID AS Employee_No, e.emp_Name AS Employee_Name, d.dl_Type AS Order_Type from empInfo e, dailyLunch d where e.emp_ID = d.emp_Id AND e.dept_Name = '"
            + cb_Department.SelectedValue + "' order by d.dl_Date", conn2);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        conn2.Open();
        da.Fill(ds); //where the exception is
        gv_Report.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

        conn2.Close();
```

Comment: what is the value of dt? Also what is the second exception?

Comment: @S.Petrosov I have updated my question, sorry about that

Comment: I guess we cannot help you that much with current information. What line throw these two exceptions, What's code just before and after that code? What are the values of those variables in these codes? Index starting from 0 or from 1? Is this column number 3 or column 2?

Comment: @HerbertYu I have added the code that I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type your data out, the datetime format may be different.

sqlite does NOT have "Date and Time Datatype", the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values.

TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").

I should write comment above, but the new email with company domain change does not allow me to write comment in SO.

Hope helps.

Comment: Thank you, I only get it when I look at the link and reference it to your post.